# Unity is not showing public methods in the event field

Tags: unity-game-engine, events

I have a class in Unity 2017 that only shows some of the public methods in the inspector.

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour 
{

    List<ShipPart> _inventory;
    int currentInvPosition = 0;
    bool invExists = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        CreateInventory(0, 0);
    }

    // Show all inventory parts as gameobjects
    public void CreateInventory(int quality, int part) 
    {
        ...
    }

    void DestroyInventory()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void ScrollInvLeft()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void ScrollInvRight()
    {
        ...
    }

    void UpdateInv(float offset)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void AddInventoryItem(ShipPart newShipPart) 
    {
        ... 
    }

    public void RemoveInventoryItem(ShipPart oldShipPart) 
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Test1(){}
    public void Test2(int i){}

}
```

I thought it might be because the invisible methods have parameters, so I added the last two methods. However they are visible in the inspector!

I am trying to call the methods from a dropdown UI element, but have also tested from a button and that cant see them either.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is kinda hard to understand from what you asked. Test1() and Test2() will be visible because they are public? DestroyInventory() is not public so not visible?

Comment: Because `ShipPart` is not a base type (int, float, string, bool, ...) you won't be able to call it using the inspector. I don't know if it would work if `ShipPart` inherits from `UnityEngine.Object` (such as `ScriptableObject`)

Comment: @Hellium - ok that explains the add/removeinv methods, however, CreateInventory uses ints and is not visible in the inspector

Comment: As Hellium said if you inherit from UnityEngine.Object you should be able to see the two methods which are hiding; though if you inherit Object then you might need to adjust some of your code

Comment: If you dont want to inherit then one solution is doing     `button.onClick.AddListener(() => yourfunctionname);` Ofcourse you will need to setup parameters for it in scripts.

Comment: `CreateInventory` has **two** parameters, and Unity is not able to handle functions that are 2 or more parameters. Check the [Unity tutorial here](https://youtu.be/J5ZNuM6K27E?t=10m30s)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As indicated in the [official Unity tutorials](https://youtu.be/J5ZNuM6K27E?t=10m29s), if you want to provide a function to an event in the inspector, the function must meet the following requirements:

1. The function must be `public`
2. The function must have a return type of `void`
3. The function must take **no** or **one** parameter
4. If the function takes one parameter, the latter must be one of the following types:

   - `int`
   - `float`
   - `string`
   - `bool`
   - `UnityEngine.Object`, or any type inheriting from `UnityEngine.Object` (such as `GameObject`, `MonoBehaviour`, `ScriptableObject`, ...)

Comment: Thank you - somehow I missed that it will only take one parameter.